# Moving div blocks vertically on window resize

Tags: css, html

http://jsfiddle.net/KZP7r/
I am trying to do something like the following but with two blocks of text instead of an image and some text.

Im trying to have two blocks of text, next to eachother horizontally, but then have the text on the right move below the text on the left when the window gets smaller.

Page im editing is here:

Hope someone can help!

```
<div class='wrapper'>
<img/>
<div class='content'>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
```

```
img{
height:200px;
width:200px;
border:1px solid grey;
}
img, .content{
float:left;
display:inline-block;
}
.content{
max-width:60%;
min-width:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Example (resize window pane left and right to see effect)](http://jsfiddle.net/g3yYC/)

Had to wrap the `left` text in a wrapper so it would float on its own.  Works brilliantly.

### CSS:

```
.content {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 150%;
    border:1px solid red;
}
@media (max-width: 539px) {
    .content, .left {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 540px) {
    .content, .left {
        float:left;
        display:inline-block;
        min-width:200px;
    }
    .content {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        max-width:60%;
    }
    .left {
        max-width: 40%;
    }
}
```

### HTML:

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='left'>Lorem Ipsum's brother on his left...</div>
    <div class='content'>Lorem Ipsum is simply...</div>
</div>
```

Use `@media` queries for this.

Answer (score 2):

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T696G/) contains a simple example of the technique. You will need some media querys to adjust the width of the containers in the minimum width that breaks columns into different lines.

You just set them to display:block, float to the left and give them a width.

```
.content{
    float:left;
    display:block;
    width: 50%;
    min-width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `float: left` just in `'img'` tag